# Can't get client_key from Behance

Tags: python, django, behance-api

I have created a new app in behance and I got the client_id. But from where will I get client_secret key and how to set redirect_uri? I don't see any places to set this. I have created app from this url https://www.behance.net/dev/apps and what I need is to authenticate user from my site by api.

And for authentication user and using "https://www.behance.net/v2/oauth/authenticate" and what parameters I have to send like client_id,redirect_uri etc. How to implement this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecxhp.png